# How to get the Textbox value from DataGridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So here I'm trying to get the Textbox filled with the selected data from the DataGridView, so when I clicked the button in the DataGridView, the selected result will be put into the Textbox, I've tried the solution from other resource but still no luck. Can somebody help? Here's the DataGridView code:

DataGridView:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelDGV" runat="server" ScrollBars="None" Height="250" Width="515">
     <asp:GridView ID="DGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
              <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCode" HeaderText="Project Code" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" />
     <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/Edit.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CommandName="CmdSearch" HeaderText="Edit">
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
              </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
                    AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
      </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

notice the button is:

```
 <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/Edit.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CommandName="CmdSearch" HeaderText="Edit">
```

oh, and the textbox's ID is "TbProjectCode", and both are in separate pages, say that 1.aspx contain the textbox and a button to open the datagridview and 2.aspx contain the datagridview and the button to select the Project Code.

thank you

Comment: Here is some documentation that pretty much tells you how to do it! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx. (Look at the example at the bottom)

Comment: it help a bit, but the DataGrid and Textbox are located in different page, any suggestion?

Comment: The text box is on a different page entirely?

Comment: yes, suppose the datagrid is in the data.aspx, it pop-up when i click a button on beside the textbox (let's say it's textbox.aspx), and when I clicked the button on the datagrid, the datagrid will close and the value will be put in previous page textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add OnRowCommand event on your gridview: OnRowCommand="DGV_OnRowCommand".

Then add this on your code behind:

```
    protected void DGV_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "CmdSearch")
        {
            int index = (int)e.CommandArgument;
            GridViewRow row = DGV.Rows[index];
            // Get the text on first cell of the row which is the project code.
            TbProjectCode.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the Project Code result to be displayed in the textbox, and btw I use VB :) and also, the datagrid and the textbox is in different page

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works well only when the DataGrid and Textbox are in the same page, but in my case the page where DataGrid and Textbox are located is different, any suggestion?

Comment: Hmmm.. can you tell me what are you using for the popup or how are you doing it?